# Objects of parent and extended models in the same table in database with Django

Tags: django, django-models

It would be very simple if I explain the question with an example:
Suppose I have a model A and multiple classes which extend A: B, C, D.
Now I want to store the objects of class A, B, C, D in the same table. Is it possible?

Comment: If models B, C, D have totally different fields? How do you imagine that on database structure level?

Comment: Fields are equal, only some functions are different.

Comment: So best way is to use proxy models, as described in answer below.

Comment: I want a model such that its objects have a function which have same signature but different implementation, which is determined when the object is created. The number of objects can be huge. Which would be a good approach to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the fields in all classes are equal then you can use the [proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) with the `Meta.proxy` attribute.